# Problema al llamar una función de una clase, desde un archivo PHP independiente

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, php5

Quiero realizar una consulta desde un archivo **`php`** a otro archivo el cual contiene *Clases y Funciones*(`POO` `PHP`). Pero a la hora de realizar la peticion no funciona:

***Mi codigo es el siguiente:***

**instancias.php**

```
<?php
//Llamamos al archivo clases.php
include("clases.php");
//Se asigna un valor a la variable funcion desde ajax
$funcion = $_POST["Funcion"];
//Se compruba que la variable este definida
if (isset($funcion)) {
    //Si la variable funcion esta defindia se realiza la comparacion mediante Switch
    switch ($funcion) {

        /**
        * Funcion Login
        **/
        //Se compara la funcion que se ejecutara y previamente se envio
        case 'Login':
            //se compara que se hayan definido las variables email y password
            $email = $_POST["Email"];
            $password = $_POST["Password"];
            if (isset($email) && isset($password)){
                $consultas = new Login();
                $consultas->iniciarLogin($email,$password);
            }else{
                echo "El correo y la contraseña no han sido definidas";
            }

            break;


    }
}else{
    echo "La Funcion a realizar no esta definida";
}
?>
```

> En esta parte del código es donde quiero llamar a la función **`iniciarLogin()`**. Esta función se encuentra dentro de la clase **`Login()`** y como dato recibe dos argumentos, el ***email y password***.

```
/**
    * Funcion Login
    **/
    //Se compara la funcion que se ejecutara y previamente se envio
    case 'Login':
        //se compara que se hayan definido las variables email y password
        $email = $_POST["Email"];
        $password = $_POST["Password"];
        if (isset($email) && isset($password)){
            $consultas = new Login();
            $consultas->iniciarLogin($email,$password);
        }else{
            echo "El correo y la contraseña no han sido definidas";
        }           
        break;
```

**clases.php**

```
<?php
//Clase general de la conexion a la base de Datos
class Conexion{


//variables para la conexion de la base de datos
protected $host_bd;
protected $user_bd;
protected $pass_bd;
protected $bd;

//variables generales
protected $credenciales;
protected $conexion_bd;
protected $consulta;
protected $query;

//Funcion de conexion a la bd
public function Conectar_BD(){


    //Se lee el archivo de configuracion .ini
    $this->credenciales = parse_ini_file("../.config/db.php.ini");
    //Se asigna el valor a las variables
    $host_bd = $this->credenciales['host'];
    $user_bd = $this->credenciales['user'];
    $pass_bd = $this->credenciales['pass'];
    $bd = $this->credenciales['db'];

    // Se hace la conexion

    try {
        $this->conexion_bd = new mysqli($host_bd,$user_bd,$pass_bd,$bd);
        echo 'Conectado';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error al conectar";
    }

    return $this->conexion_bd;
}

//funcion para cerrar la conexion
public function cerrarConexion(){
    $this->conexion_bd = null;
}

}

/*===================================
=            Clase login con  herencia de la clase Conexion         =
===================================*/

class Login extends Conexion{

    public function iniciarLogin($correo,$contrasena){
            /*Consulta con Sentencia preparada*/
        try{
            //De la clase heredada "Conexion" se obtiene la funcion Conectar_BD
            $this->Conectar_BD();
            //Se asigna la cadena de texto de la consulta de MySQL
            $this->query = 'SELECT CONCAT(empleados.nombre_empleado," ",empleados.apellido_paterno," ", empleados.apellido_materno) as NombreEmpleado, tipo_usuario.rol FROM tipo_usuario inner join usuarios on tipo_usuario.id_tipousuario=usuarios.id_tipo_usuario inner join empleados on usuarios.id_empleado=empleados.id_empleado inner join estado on empleados.id_estado=estado.id_estado where estado.estado=1 and correo=? and contraseña=?;';
            //Preparamos la sentencia a executar
            $this->consulta = $this->conexion_bd->prepare($this->query);
            //Asignacion de los valores de la sentencia preparada
            $this->consulta->bind_param('ss',$correo,$contrasena);
            //Ejecucion de la sentencia
            $this->consulta->execute();
            //Se almacena el resultado
            $this->consulta->store_result();
            //Vincular nombres a la sentencia preparada
            $this->consulta->bind_result($nombre,$rol);
            //Se obtienen las filas de la consulta
            $num_rows = $this->consulta->num_rows;
            //Seteamos el header de "content-type" como "JSON" para que jQuery lo reconozca como tal
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            //Se compara si existe al menos un resultado de la consulta
            if ($num_rows>=1) {
                //Se obtienen los resultados de la consulta
                while ($this->consulta->fetch()) {
                    //Se guardan los datos en un arreglo
                    $datos_json = array('Nombre' => $nombre , 'Rol' => $rol );
                }
                //Se devuelve el array pasado a JSON como objeto
                echo json_encode($datos_json,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
            } else {
                echo "No hay registros";
            }

        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo 'Error al hacer la consulta';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Y el error cual es??

Comment: El error es que no ejecuta la función, me tiene que mandar el resultado de la consulta (Estoy uñusando Ajax). Estaba debugeando el código, quite ese código y puse un echo para ver si devolvía valores y todo bien, el problema se produce al instancias la clase y funcion, que no hace nada devuelve el fail del Ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haciendo debug y aplicando algunas banderas, puede llegar a la conclusion que el conflicto estaba en los datos `JSON`, pero específicamente:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

El cual estaba generando una especie de conflicto, leyendo un poco encontré que no era tan indispensable, ya que se detecta el tipo de datos que se esta utilizando.

La solución solución fue solo removerlo y de esta manera la consulta ya me arrojo los datos esperados.

Answer (score 1):

He realizado solo alguno cambias a tu codigo y quedaria de esta manera:

**clases.php**

```
/*===================================
=            Clase login con  herencia de la clase Conexion         =
===================================*/

class Login extends Conexion{

    //Son los parametros que vas a recibir al instanciar la Clase ($correo, password)
    public function iniciarLogin($correo,$password){

        try{

            $this->Conectar_BD();

            //Considero cambiar tu campo (contraseña) por (password)
            //Ejemplo de una consulta
            $this->query = 'SELECT nombre, correo 
                            FROM usuarios WHERE correo=? AND password=?;';

            $this->consulta = $this->conexion_bd->prepare($this->query);
            $this->consulta->bind_param('ss',$correo,$password);
            $this->consulta->execute();

            $this->consulta->store_result();

            $this->consulta->bind_result($nombre,$correo);

            $num_rows = $this->consulta->num_rows;

            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            if ($num_rows>=1) {
                while ($this->consulta->fetch()) {

                    $datos_json = array('Nombre' => $nombre , 'Correo' => $correo );

                }
                echo json_encode($datos_json,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
            } else {
                echo "No hay registros";
            }

        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo 'Error al hacer la consulta';
        }
    }
}
```

**instancias.php**

```
<?php
include("clases.php");

$funcion = $_POST["funcion"];

if (isset($funcion)) {

    switch ($funcion) {

        case 'Login':
            //se compara que se hayan definido las variables email y password
            $email = $_POST["email"];
            $password = $_POST["password"];

            if (isset($email) && isset($password)){

                $consultas = new Login();
                $consultas->iniciarLogin($email,$password);

            }else{
                echo "El correo y la contraseña no han sido definidas";
            }

            break;


    }
}else{
    echo "La Funcion a realizar no esta definida";
}
?>
```

Estoy haciendo pruebas localmente y si funciona.
Espero poder ayudar, saludos.

Comment: Realmente el problema no tiene que ver con el nombre de las columnas de la base de datos, el problema estaba en `header('Content-Type: application/json')` me generaba una especie de conflicto, al quitarlo ya me muestra el resultado, de todas formas gracias.

Comment: Muy bien me da gusto que solucionaras tu problema. Saludos.